# Preventing jQuery from queing multiple times

Tags: jquery, queue

I'm trying to make a clever contact page. I've got my jQuery animations all working correctly, the only thing left is that I want to prevent animations from queueing up a bunch when you roll over the links quickly.

Typically, I know you can use .stop() to prevent that, but I'm not sure how to do it in this scenario. So:

1. How do I prevent jquery animations from queueing up multiple times on mouse-over?
2. If anyone wants to provide insight on how to clean up my messy jQuery, that would be a bonus.

Working code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpE64/) (mouse over the button links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work for me on a dropdown menu:

```
.stop(true, true)
```

In context, in my code:

```
$('#smoothmenu1 li').hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hover');
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: No problem! I had just gone through this issue a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SpE64/2/

Comment: Thanks Godwin- That seems to work really well if you mouse over the same button multiple times, but if you mouse horizontally across all of them real quick, it slowly goes through each of the animations one at a time. That's what I'm hoping to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this plugin. It allows you to regulate how often/how many times an event can fire.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

There's hoverintent.js http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html though it doesn't seem like it's been recently updated. To be frank, I don't know if it's still in favor with the jQuery crowd, but once upon a time it was heavily recommended for stuff like this.

Comment: I still use hoverIntent sometimes